# Single line command/script to archive a certain amount of folders

Tags: linux, compression

I'm looking for a single line command or a script that archives 5 folders into .tar files (no gzip/bzip needed) in a certain directory and deletes the folders after a successful compression. It has to use the original folder name as file name for the archive too.

So far I've used the current command, which only does one directory per time:

```
tar -c directory > directory.tar && rm -rf directory
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will process the first five directories under the directory passed as an argument to the script.

```
#!/bin/bash
c=1
for directory in $1/*
do
    if [[ -d "$directory" ]]
    then
        tar -cf "${directory}.tar" "$directory" && rm -rf "$directory"
        if (( c++ > 5 ))
        then
            break
        fi
    fi
done
```

I'm curious about the reason for the limit.

Comment: The limit is simply to avoid folder that shouldn't be from being archived

Comment: `tar -cf "${directory}.tar" "$directory" && rm -rf "directory"` should be `tar -cf "${directory}.tar" "$directory" && rm -rf "$directory"`, right?

Comment: @EarthMind: Yes, that was a typo. I've fixed it. Wouldn't it be better to specify which *particular* directories (by name or other criteria) you want archived or to *exclude* particular directories (by name, etc.) rather than just saying "archive the first five"?

Comment: Yes, that would be a much better way indeed. I just wanted to keep it simple at first.

Answer (score 1):

it's a bit lengthy but:

```
for i in dir1 dir2 dir3; do tar -cf $i.tar $i; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then rm -rf $i; fi; done
```

edit; `tar -cf dir.tar dir` is a little more concise than `tar -c dir > dir.tar`

example script:

```
#!/bin/sh
DIR=$1
tar -cf $DIR.tar $DIR/
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  rm -rf $DIR
fi
```

you can plop that into `script.sh`, `chmod 755 script.sh` and then run it like `script.sh directory`

however, you could add a lot more to it, to get a list of directories from your main directory, and even use a file to keep track of the last time `directory` was archived, so you can set your maximum, etc.

Comment: What does the `if [ $? -eq 0 ];` check for?

Comment: `$?` is the return value for the `tar` command, 0 is successful

Comment: Won't `$i` contain a slash? If so the script won't create the archives.

Comment: `$i` may contain a slash if you're doing `for i in *` but you could remove it with `sed`, but again, we're getting pretty complicated, and this might work better as a multi-line script, for clarity; edit: doing a quick check, trailing slash is not printed with `for i in *; do echo $i; done`

Answer (score 0):

```
for dir in dir1 dir2 dir3 dir4 dir5 ; do tar -c "$dir" > "$dir".tar && rm -rf "$dir" ; done
```

Comment: Is there an alternative without hardcoding the directory names?

Comment: if all the directories are in one directory, you can do `for i in /directory/*`

Comment: They are in the same directory but I need to set a maximum so that it doesn't archive all the directories.

Comment: a maximum? this is one line to fit into a `crontab`, i presume? as you get more complicated, you might want to think about writing this out to a script file, and then calling that script in the crontab... that'd be much cleaner.

Comment: A script would be nice too. One that would allow me to execute it this way: script.sh directory

Comment: `for dir in "$@" ; do tar -c "$dir" > "$dir".tar && rm -rf "$dir" ; done`